# Solution runtime varies dramatically

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, c++14

I was solving valid tic tac toe solution on leetcode and I have greatly puzzled by my leetcode submissions runtimes.

For e.g. I ran the same code  multiple times (with absolutely no change whatsoever)

There seem to be huge variations in the runtimes.Sometimes, it takes 0ms , sometimes 9ms, sometimes 7ms ,sometimes 5ms.

[Leetcode solution runtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/preQZ.png)

Why is this happening ? Is my code structured badly ?(Memory leak happening )
My code just in case - somebody want to see it.

```cpp
class Solution {

public:
        
    bool validTicTacToe(vector<string>& board) {
        
        int i,j,a[8]={0},b[8]={0};
        int o=0,x=0;
        string s="";
        
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]=='X')
                {x++;
                 a[i]++;
                 a[j+3]++;
                if(i==j)
                    a[6]++;
                if(j==2-i)
                    a[7]++;
                }
                else if(board[i][j]=='O')
                {   o++;
                    b[i]++;
                    b[j+3]++;
                if(i==j)
                    b[6]++;
                if(j==2-i)
                    b[7]++;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==3)
            {s="a";
             break;
            }
             
            if(b[i]==3)
            {s="b";break;

            }
        }
        
        
        if(s=="" && o+x<9)
            s="p";
        else if(s=="")
            s="d";
        
        if(s=="d" && x!=5)
            return false;
        
        if(s=="b" && o!=x)
            return false;
        
        if(s=="a" && ((o+1)!=x))
            return false;
        
        
        if(s=="p")
        {
            if(o==x)
                return true;
            else if(x==o+1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Most computers aren't that good at giving time down in the milliseconds. Often the minimum timing resolution used to be something sad and pathetic (but power saving) like 1/64th of a second. These days it's better, but not that much better.

Comment: That said, if your program is leaking, I'd fix that first before worrying about performance.  Bug-free > fast. That said, I'm not seeing anything in the program that can possibly leak.

Comment: OT: `string s="";`  you don't need the `=""` part. The constructor for string will already initialize it to an empty string by default.

Comment: Structure-wise, give things descriptive names. It's a lot easier to see that `defrobulator` defrobulates than it is to see that `s` defrobulates.

Comment: It's hard to know the relevance of timing results if you don't know how the time was measured. For all we know some other, more important tasks were running and starving your program of access to a required resource like RAM, disk, or CPU cores.

Comment: I played with leetcode some time, their measurement is always inaccurate. Just ignore it.

Comment: On leetcode you share cpu time with other users so runtime will vary because of that too.  But in general : Just stay away from Leetcode if you want to learn C++. Most solutions shown there are of appalling quality (really). And you will mostly pickup bad habits that you will need to unlearn if you want to get a job in software engineering.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am practicing leetcode as most companies ask leetcode medium in their job interviews. It is there only that I get variety of questions to solve. What alternative do you sugggest ?

Comment: In a way, that's kind of interesting. When hiring I'm looking for problem solving skills along with a side order of "Do they really know the languages I'm hiring for?" That results in two totally different types of questions and the problem solving questions generally have little-to-nothing to do with software. I don't even care about the answer; I want to see how the applicant attacks the problem. The language questions are focusing on practical use of the language. Do they apply RAII? Observe the Rule of Three? Know the intermediate-level syntax? You don't get that out of judge quizes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Linico Really they do that? Maybe its time to point out to them that leetcode is fine for exploring problem solving skills but a horrible place for software engineers because the code hasn't anything to do with software engineering. E.g. Abstraction, Unit testing, Design patterns, knowledge of the actual language and writing readable/maintainable code based on implementing interfaces. All I know is I wouldn't be hiring on Leetcode skills :  I would focus, on software engineering skills, being able to work in a team and a willingnes/capability to keep learning/adapting.